# C# When I open the console, there is no command entered and it immediately disappears

Tags: c#, python-3.x, wpf, cmd

```
private void RunApp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.7\InstallPath");
        if (key != null)
        {
            object path = key.GetValue("ExecutablePath");
            string comm = "/C " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path as string) + @"\python " + 
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((string)SelectProjectFolder.Content) + "main.py";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", comm);
        }
    }
```

Where is the mistake? The console opens without a command and immediately closes. What to do with etip. I need to run a .py file through the console. I get the path to Python via Key and add the path to the Py file. But when you open a command in the console, no. (Google translator)

Comment: Use debugger to check content of comm variable before process.start is called

Comment: What is expected behavior, for example when you double click yhe py file

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `"/C"` to the command window, which means *"Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates"* (type `cmd.exe /?` at the command line to see all the arguments it accepts, along with a description of each).

Instead, try passing `"/K"` if you want the window to remain:

```
string comm = "/K " + …
```

Then you should be able to see what error is being reported (if any).

---

Most likely you are missing a backslash character (`'\'`) between `SelectProjectFolder.Content` and `"main.py"`. To resolve this, it's usually favored to use `Path.Combine` to create directory paths:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName((string)SelectProjectFolder.Content)), "main.py")
```

---

Another thing you might want to do is try various registry keys, if the problem is that the path to python.exe is not found. I *think* these are correct, but they should be validated:

```
private string GetPythonExePath(string ver = "3.7")
{
    return (Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey($@"SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\{ver}\InstallPath")?
        .GetValue("ExecutablePath") ??
            Registry.CurrentUser
                .OpenSubKey($@"Software\Python\PythonCore\{ver}\InstallPath")?
                .GetValue("ExecutablePath") ??
            Registry.LocalMachine
                .OpenSubKey($@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\{ver}\InstallPath")?
                .GetValue("ExecutablePath"))?
        .ToString();
}
```

Also, you can set the path to your python file separately from the `Process.Start` command, to make debugging a little easier (you can set a breakpoint on the `Process.Start` line and examine the arguments before launching the process):

```
var pythonExePath = GetPythonExePath();            

if (pythonExePath!=null)
{
    var pythonFile = Path.Combine(SelectProjectFolder.Content.ToString(), "main.py");
    Process.Start("cmd.exe", $"/K {pythonExePath} {pythonFile}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ProcessStartInfo:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\Python";
string args = "main.py";
ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
pinfo.Arguments = args;
using(Process proc = Process.Start(pinfo))
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
    if(proc.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        // Normal exit
    }
    else
    {
        // Exit with error
    }
}
```

ProcessStartInfo can be used if you have a reference to System.Diagnostics in your code.